# Is interaction between ResultSet and ResultSetMetaData one-way?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

A colleague of mine pulled some code from the web that does something like the following:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
while (rs.next()) {
  count = rsmd.getColumnCount();
  validateSame(firstRowCount, count);
}
```

This implies that the RSMD is maintaining an internal reference to the `ResultSet` and the column count could vary by row.

It seems intuitive to me that there would be one set of metadata per RS, and I'd like to refactor this code out, but I haven't been able to verify this in the Java documentation or get at it through Google searches.  Could someone please confirm or deny that the metadata is constant?

Comment: lets fix third line too -- `getColumnCount()` is a method of `ResultSetMetaData`. I do not have a formal document, but as far as I know yes, it is safe to retrieve metadata only once, when you start processing a result set.

Comment: *This implies that the RSMD is maintaining an internal reference to the ResultSet and the column count could vary by row.*: I fail to see how it implies that. The posted code doesn't even use the metadata.

Comment: A little hard for me to answer your questions since you've edited it and I have no idea what it looked like before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SQL result set is a table whose structure is defined entirely by the query and the underlying table(s) being queried. It cannot vary row by row. You can refactor this.